# elemento <option > de un <select> seleccionado por defecto

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un select con una sola opcion fija desabilitada, las demas opciones se las agrego tras una consulta ajax, necesito que al cargar la página se seleccione la opcion fija con el disable.

```
<select id="desdeReserveInput" name="desde" class="form-control">
      <option value="lugar" selected disabled>Lugar</option>
</select>
```

Aqui el jquery que añade las demás opciones:

```
lugares.forEach(function (item) {                
      var desdeOption = document.createElement('option');
      desdeOption.value = item['nombre'];
      desdeOption.innerHTML = item['nombre'];
      desde.appendChild(desdeOption);          
});
```

Reitero, la única dificultad que tengo es que cuando se carga la página se selecciona automaticamente la primera opcion que agrego con jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tu problema es que no asignas el valor del `select` en ningún momento.

Tenes que usar la propiedad [value](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_value.asp)

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo

```js
var select = document.getElementById('test')
//Loop para agregar datos para ejemplificar
for(var i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
  var opcion =  document.createElement('option');
  opcion.value = "item "+i;
  opcion.innerHTML = "item "+i;
  select.appendChild(opcion);          
}

//Asigno el valor "defecto" a el objeto select (por lo que automáticamente se selecciona la opción son dicho value
select.value = "defecto";
```

```html
<select name="" id="test">
   <option value="defecto" disabled>Valor por defecto</option>      
</select>
```

Comment: Gracias Juan, funciona perfecto.